# Keycloak user registration and auth from Flutter (also using traefik and docker)

Tags: flutter, keycloak-rest-api

I want to make user registration available from flutter preferably using my own UI so not redirecting them to Keycloak registration page but at this point I am fine with that too.

I couldn't find any basic tutorial that shows how to config Keycloak as well as to send the api request (through flutter).

Could you help me with any source?
I have tried using this in my Flutter app:

```
Future<bool> registerUser(String email, String password) async {
    final registerUrl =
        Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2:8081/admin/realms/myrealm/users');
    const clientSecret = 'myclientSecret'; 

    final registrationData = {
      'username': email,
      'password': password,
      'email': email,
    };

    final response = await http.post(
      registerUrl,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $clientSecret',
      },
      body: json.encode(registrationData),
    );
    return response.statusCode == 201;
  }
```

I have tried all kinds of client secrets Now I use the client secret of "realm-management" client because it has user-management but I get 404 as response, the best I could get was 401 with clients that had base url.

Answer (score 0):

Try with admin secret instead client secret

headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'Authorization': 'Bearer **$adminSecret**',
}

'http://localhost:8080/**admin**/realms/myrealm/users'